# Firebase signed up users - Storing users in node vs in registered users

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

How do I store users in a node rather than just in Registered Users, which is what the current code is doing (in firebase) Here is the code login controller i have THANKS :

```
app.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
```

$scope.data = {};

$scope.signupEmail = function(){

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");

ref.createUser({
  email    : $scope.data.email,
  password : $scope.data.password
}, function(error, userData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
  }
});
```

};

Comment: Note that this is described in [Firebase's documentation on Storing User Data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing). You'd do well to read that entire [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/). It covers many topics and answers the most common questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant user data is stored in the userData-object.
to save it you can just do something like this:

```
ref.createUser({
    email    : $scope.data.email,
    password : $scope.data.password
}, function(error, userData) {
    if (error) {
    console.log("Error creating user:", error);
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
        ref.child('users').push(userData); 
    //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I appreciate you help, Im just learning firebase !! If I were to add to the email as a child of that specific user, what would that look like?

Comment: the e-mail is actually saved as a child. inside of the userData-object there is an object "password" with the property "email". Here are the according [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html)